# IE8 jquery ajax head request not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, internet-explorer-8

typical IE problems everyone.  this works in chrome, firefox, safari - but not in IE8.  haven't tried in IE9 yet.  anyone know what i'm missing? i tried it with and without the crossDomain param.  thanks in advance.

```
$.ajax({
  url:'http://www.example.com/photo.jpg',
  type:'HEAD',
  crossDomain:true,
  error: function() {
    // something bad
  },
  success: function() {
    // something cool
  }
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From here http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/:

**type**

**Default**: 'GET'

The type of request to make ("POST" or "GET"), default is "GET". Note: Other HTTP request methods, such as PUT and DELETE, can also be used here, but they are not supported by all browsers.

Comment: So basically, tell OP to use `GET`?

Comment: that's lame, i guess i could file this under RTFM.  thanks for responding.